# I am trying to develop an async iterator to display a live log being written by another process

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

Process A is doing a test authentication against an active directory server.  As it goes through each of the steps it stores a log entry in a mysql memoory table.

After the user enters their credentials into a small form, a new window is displayed, with the intention of showing the abovementioned log step by step as process A goes through its sequence.

In order to get the data from the table I use an await fetch that calls my php api.  The API responds with one log record per request, and then removes that record from the table.  I have verified that this code works.

I then wrote an iterator to run the above code, retrieving each individual record and showing it on the log window.  Ther iterator is called using Javascript's "for await of" construct.  I can see from the network tab of developer tools that the promises for these records are being resolved, however inside the "for await of construct" the promises are still pending with a value of undefined.

As I stated earlier, their are two await fetches that run simultaneously.  Here is the code that attempts the ldap authentication (it works with no problems)

```
let postVars = new FormData();
    postVars.append('action', "40.5");
    postVars.append('username', uname);
    postVars.append('password', password);

    const options = {
        method: 'post',
        body: postVars,
    };
    await fetch('/admin/adminFuncs.php', options).then(result => result.json()).then(result => {
        let message;

        message = 'Error:' + result.err + ' ' + result.errorMessage + ' ';
        message = message + '\n' + result.errorsArray.toString();
        message = message + '\n' + result.rebinds.toString();
        console.log(message);
```

The actual communication with the active directory happens in php.

Now here is the await fetch construct that calls the api to retrieve and delete one line of the log written by the previous api call.

```
async function getNextLogEntry() {
    postVars = new FormData;
    postVars.append('action', "40.6");
    const options = {
        method: 'post',
        body: postVars,
    };
    await fetch('/admin/adminFuncs.php', options)
        .then(result => result.json())
```

As I mentioned I developed an async iteraator to grab records one at a time from the previous function.  Here it is.

```
const END_OF_LOG = '---';
const asyncLogEntryIterable = {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        let i=0;
        return {
            next() {
                i++;
                const done = logLine === END_OF_LOG;
                const value = done ? undefined : getNextLogEntry();
                // return Promise.resolve({value, done});
                return { value, done };
            },
            return() {
                return { done: true};
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now here is the code that calls these processes,

```
    if (event.target.id === 'testAuthenticationButton') {
            submitAuthenticationTest().finally();
            testAuthenticationDiv.style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('authenticationLog').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('testAuthentication').style.display = 'none';
            const authenticationLog = document.getElementById('authenticationLog');
            authenticationLog.style.display = 'block';
            authenticationLog.style.borderStyle = '1px solid black';
            // showAuthenticationLog();

            (async () => {
                for await (const x of asyncLogEntryIterable) {
                    console.log(x.logLine);
                }
            })();
        }
    })
```

Right now this code is doing a console.llog instead of putting it in the window, but the behavior is the same regardless.  Each of the records logs as undefined, and well before the promises have resolved.  After the promises resolve, I can see the data in each transaction.

I am relatively new to asynchronous programming, and so I am probably missing something obvious.  Any help you can offer will be most appreciated and will go a long way to helping me understand this paradigm.

Comment: Please make sure that your code is valid -- it has unbalanced braces in several code blocks. It has undefined variables, like `logLine` in the `next()` method (use strict mode to avoid this). Also the indentation is not right.

Comment: You may want to use an asynchronous generator function - much simpler.

Comment: The `next` method needs to return a promise for the `{value, done}` object, not an object where the `value` is a promise.